# Blank Screen Installing Db2 Developer Community Edition on Linux

Tags: db2

RHEL 7.3 64-bit. The installer got to the installation screen with progress bar and the last thing I saw was that it was downloading some Docker files. When I came back to check on it, all I see is a blank screen:

[image]

Help menu says the installer is version 1.1.2 (7/21/2017). The installer was run as root and here is the console:

```
# ./ibm-db2-developer_community_edition-1.1.2-x86_64.AppImage 
installed: X-AppImage-BuildId=0d7243c0-6e2f-11a7-104f-052bf6805623 image: X-AppImage-BuildId=0d7243c0-6e2f-11a7-104f-052bf6805623
in the prod if statement

<--- Last few GCs --->

[9612:0xf9a24997000]  1886826 ms: Mark-sweep 2052.0 (2163.0) -> 2052.0 (2132.0) MB, 2896.2 / 16.6 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 2896 ms) last resort 
[9612:0xf9a24997000]  1889720 ms: Mark-sweep 2052.0 (2132.0) -> 2051.8 (2132.0) MB, 2893.7 / 16.2 ms  last resort 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x18383e6f3c49 <String[7]: file://>
    2: urlParse(aka urlParse) [url.js:75] [pc=0x2c284f17c0d1](this=0x2ed7d9f02311 <undefined>,url=0x33aaf09482d1 <String[17]: random500x500.jpg>,parseQueryString=0x2ed7d9f02421 <false>,slashesDenoteHost=0x2ed7d9f023b1 <true>)
    3: resolve [url.js:646] [pc=0x2c284f172914](this=0x33aaf0944c91 <an Url with map 0x345eb885f1c1>,relative=0x33aaf09482d1 <String[17]: random500x500.jpg>)
    ...
```

It has been hung like this for a while and the process is not using any CPU.

**Edit**: I re-ran the installer and watched it more closely this time. Now, it's stuck at 18%:

[image]

About every 5 seconds, `ibm-db2-develop` pops up to pretty high CPU for a few seconds. I attached strace with `strace -f -tt -o outputfile.txt -p ${PID}` and I noticed some HTTP 404s and 429s in the read syscalls:

```
21477 13:45:17.682583 read(42, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Tue, 05 S"..., 65536) = 200
21477 13:45:19.700105 read(43, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-"..., 65536) = 230
21477 13:45:19.700717 read(59, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-"..., 65536) = 236
21477 13:45:19.731156 read(42, "HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests\r\n"..., 65536) = 763
```

It looks like most of the requests are for some kind of speed test, although some seem to be related to Docker containers:

```
[pid 21477] 14:40:48.397771 write(61, "GET /mini/speedtest/latency.txt "..., 213) = 213
[pid 21477] 14:40:48.710338 write(60, "GET /speedtest/latency.txt HTTP/"..., 205) = 205
[pid 21477] 14:40:49.479746 write(43, "GET /speedtest-config.php HTTP/1"..., 198) = 198
[pid 21477] 14:40:49.821431 write(43, "GET /speedtest-servers-static.ph"..., 206) = 206
[pid 21477] 14:40:51.707073 write(43, "GET /containers/dsm/logs?follow="..., 159) = 159
[pid 21477] 14:40:51.707302 write(62, "GET /containers/db2server/logs?f"..., 165) = 165
[pid 21477] 14:40:55.707913 write(66, "GET /containers/dsm/logs?follow="..., 159) = 159
[pid 21477] 14:40:55.709166 write(67, "GET /containers/db2server/logs?f"..., 165) = 165
[pid 21477] 14:40:56.416893 write(42, "GET /speedtest/random350x350.jpg"..., 214) = 214
[pid 21477] 14:40:56.736215 write(61, "GET /speedtest/random350x350.jpg"..., 214) = 214
[pid 21477] 14:40:57.511335 write(60, "GET /speedtest-config.php HTTP/1"..., 198) = 198
[pid 21477] 14:40:57.850798 write(60, "GET /speedtest-servers-static.ph"..., 206) = 206
[pid 21477] 14:40:59.702378 write(60, "GET /containers/dsm/logs?follow="..., 159) = 159
[pid 21477] 14:40:59.702467 write(62, "GET /containers/db2server/logs?f"..., 165) = 165
[pid 21477] 14:41:03.706587 write(66, "GET /containers/dsm/logs?follow="..., 159) = 159
[pid 21477] 14:41:03.706808 write(67, "GET /containers/db2server/logs?f"..., 165) = 165
[pid 21477] 14:41:04.436802 write(60, "GET /speedtest/latency.txt HTTP/"..., 208) = 208
[pid 21477] 14:41:04.762171 write(60, "GET /speedtest/latency.txt HTTP/"..., 209) = 209
[pid 21477] 14:41:05.535974 write(61, "GET /speedtest/latency.txt HTTP/"..., 207) = 207
[pid 21477] 14:41:05.871157 write(61, "GET /mini/speedtest/latency.txt "..., 213) = 213
[pid 21477] 14:41:07.705146 write(61, "GET /containers/dsm/logs?follow="..., 159) = 159
[pid 21477] 14:41:07.705354 write(62, "GET /containers/db2server/logs?f"..., 165) = 165
[pid 21477] 14:41:11.706155 write(66, "GET /containers/dsm/logs?follow="..., 159) = 159
[pid 21477] 14:41:11.706352 write(67, "GET /containers/db2server/logs?f"..., 165) = 165
[pid 21477] 14:41:12.457648 write(43, "GET /speedtest/latency.txt HTTP/"..., 205) = 205
[pid 21477] 14:41:12.786219 writev(42, [{"POST /api/api.php HTTP/1.1\r\nrefe"..., 438}, {"", 0}], 2) = 438
```

**Edit**: I used the `-s` argument of `strace` to dump more of the response and the container requests are returning 404s:

```
[pid 21477] 14:45:35.713220 read(66, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\nServer: Docker/1.10.2 (linux)\r\nX-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\nDate: Tue, 05 Sep 2017 21:45:35 GMT\r\nContent-Length: 23\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\nNo such container: dsm\n", 65536) = 230
[pid 21477] 14:45:35.714067 read(67, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\nServer: Docker/1.10.2 (linux)\r\nX-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\nDate: Tue, 05 Sep 2017 21:45:35 GMT\r\nContent-Length: 29\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\nNo such container: db2server\n", 65536) = 236
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution is to disable SELinux:

```
sudo setenforce Permissive
```

I have confirmed this and installed the product successfully:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                  NAMES
a6897b6ff68f        dsm:v2.1.4_2             "/opt/start_dsm.sh"      16 hours ago        Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:11080-11082->11080-11082/tcp   dsm
3085e6a8bb4b        db2server:v11.1.2fp2_2   "/var/db2_setup/lib/e"   16 hours ago        Up About an hour    22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp       db2server
```

Comment: @govind-samrow Please explain why you are deleting valid answers.

Comment: @chunjef Please explain why you recommended this for deletion.

Comment: Does `sudo setenforce Permissive` survive a reboot on Centos 7 ?

Comment: @mao It seemed to only be necessary to disable SELinux during the installation; however, you can disable it permanently by editing `/etc/selinux/config`